# How to sum columns in csv file in python more efficiently

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This is my data:

```
Year    Country     Albania     Andorra     Armenia     Austria   Azerbaijan
2009    Lithuania      0           0           0           0           1    
2009    Israel         0           7           0           0           0    
2008    Israel         1           2           2           0           4
2008    Lithuania      1           5           1           0           8
```

Actually, it is csv file and delimiter is , so raw data is:

```
Year,Country,Albania,Andorra,Armenia,Austria,Azerbaijan
2009,Lithuania,0,0,0,0,1
2009,Israel,0,7,0,0,0
2008,Israel,1,2,2,0,4
2008,Lithuania,1,5,1,0,8
```

where the first element of the list means sum by column for Lithuania and the second element means sum by column for Israel (for Albania column)?

I am a beginner in python and don't really know many python tricks. What I do know is that I probably complicate too much in my code.

And I want to get this:

```
final_dict = {Albania: [1, 1], Andorra: [5, 9], Armenia: [1, 2], Austria: [0, 0], Azerbaijan: [9, 4]}
```

Explanation of output: for every country in first row (Albania, Andorra, Armenia, Austria and Azerbaijan) I want to get sum by countries from Country column.

```
Andorra: [5,9] 
# 5 is sum for Lithuania in Andorra column
# 9 is sum for Israel in Andorra column
```

Comment: You requested a dictionary of lists, indexed by country... so you have
to maintain _separately_ a correspondence between the other country
and each sequential elements in the list.

It seems to me that the natural data structure to hold your result is
a dictionary of dictionaries.  Won't it be a better solution to have
`final_dict = {'Albania':{'Israel':1, 'Lithuania':1},
'Andorra':{'Israel':9, 'Lithuania':5}, ... }` ?

If you organize the final data like that, you then can do `print
final_dict['Andorra']['Lithuania']`.  _Disclaimer: I wrote an answer
that gives you exactly that_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you want the the lines aggregated by year:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("songfestival.csv", "r") as ifile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
    country_columns = [k for k in reader.fieldnames if k not in ["Year","Country"]]
    data = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
    for line in reader:
        curr_country = data[line["Country"]]
        for country_column in country_columns:
            curr_country[country_column] += int(line[country_column])

    with open("songfestival_aggr.csv", "w") as ofile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(ofile, fieldnames=country_columns+["Country"])
        writer.writeheader()
        for k, v in data.items():
            row = dict(v)
            row["Country"] = k
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I toke the liberty to output it in another csv file. Your data struct is very error prone, since it depends on the order of the columns. Better to use an intermediate dict in a dict to assign names to the aggregations -> see @gboffi's comment on your question.

Comment: This is just whole columns in lists, but what I really need is grouped values by rows (as you can see in first table, there are 2 different countries for 2 years, but actually there are then many countries that are not in the same order). How should I do that?

Comment: @thecoparyew: I then do not completely get the expected output. Can you update your question with a set of inputdata and the expected output for that data?

Comment: @RickyA I updated it, I hope it is more clear what I want to do now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the Pandas module](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is perfect for this type of application:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('songfestival.csv')
gb = df.groupby('Country')
res = pd.concat([i[1].sum(numeric_only=True) for i in gb], axis=1).T
res.pop('Year')
order = [i[0] for i in gb]

print(order)
print(res)

#['Israel', 'Lithuania']
#   Albania  Andorra  Armenia  Austria  Azerbaijan
#0        1        9        2        0           4
#1        1        5        1        0           9
```

to query the result for each column you can simply do:

```
print(res.Albania)
print(res.Andorra)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hattrick is using [the defaultdict from the collections module](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-objects.html), please search for

> python defaultdict

on SO, you'll find lot of useful examples, and here is my answer

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# slurp the data
data = list(csv.reader(open('points.csv')))

# massage the data
for i, row in enumerate(data[1:],1):
    data[i] = [int(elt) if elt.isdigit() else elt for elt in row]

points = {} # an empty dictionary
for i, country in enumerate(data[0][2:],2):
    # for each country, a couple country:defaultdict is put in points
    points[country] = defaultdict(int)
    for row in data[1:]:
        opponent = row[1]
        points[country][opponent] += row[i]

# here you can  post-process  points as you like,
# I'll simply print out the stuff
for country in points:
    for opponent in points[country]:
        print country, "vs", opponent, "scored",
        print points[country][opponent], "points."
```

The example output for your data has been

```
Andorra vs Israel scored 9 points.
Andorra vs Lithuania scored 5 points.
Austria vs Israel scored 0 points.
Austria vs Lithuania scored 0 points.
Albania vs Israel scored 1 points.
Albania vs Lithuania scored 1 points.
Azerbaijan vs Israel scored 4 points.
Azerbaijan vs Lithuania scored 9 points.
Armenia vs Israel scored 2 points.
Armenia vs Lithuania scored 1 points.
```

**Edit**

If you're against `defaultdict`, you can use the `.get` method of an ordinary `dict`, that allows you to have back an optional default value if the `key:value` pair was not initialised

```
    points[country] = {} # a standard empty dict
    for row in data[1:]:
        opponent = row[1]
        points[country][opponent] = points[country].get(opponent,0) + row[i]
```

as you see, it's a bit clumsier, but still manageable.